# How can I move a Motion Tracked Camera Solve on the timeline?

Tags: animation, camera, constraints, timeline

I motion tracked a scene in blender. I now want to add frames to the beginning of my time line and thought the best way to do that would be add frames to the end and move everything forward along the time line creating the space I want at the head of the scene.

The problem is I am unable to move the camera and its motion animation/constraint from where they are in the time line. I don't see any info in the timeline or dope sheet for the motion track data. What am I doing wrong?

Debbi :)

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing anything of your interface, the _Timeline_, maybe the scene, _Outliner_ panel or anything. Do you have the camera selected?